# Add element to an existing 2d list whilst matching the position

Tags: python, list, loops, matrix

So I have one list (A):

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

And I am looping through a series of string values that correspond to a larger  list (B):

```
=[[1,open],[3,open],[4,closed],[5,closed],[6,open],[7,open],[8,open],[9,open],[10,open],
[11,open],[12,open],[13,open],[14,open],[15,open],[16,open],[17,open],[18,open],[19,open]]
```

Now the result I want is a final 2d list C:

```
[[1,open],[2,""],[3,open],[4,""],[5,""]]
```

The logic of which is that if, for each number in A, there exists a number in B and the description in B is "open" then duplicate to C otherwise return the number and "". The numbers in B can be in any order as well so a 1 to 1 mapping wouldn't work here. I've tried to cycle through but these lists are very large and I have to cycle through the entire list of B (or atleast until I find the number) each time I go through the elements of A and this takes a lot of time.

Thanks

Comment: You may convert `[[1,open],[3,open],[4,closed],[5,closed],[6,open]]` to `{1:open, 3:open, 4:closed, 5:closed, 6:open}` . It will make things easier.

Comment: If open is not meant to be the builtin (which opens a file), you need to enclose it with " as well, and closed needs them for sure.